# How do I list the user permissions of all users?

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmqctl

I know that I can get the permissions of a specific user via `rabbitmqctl list_user_permissions myuser` but how can I do that easily for all users?

I couldn't find anything on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

I know this works in bash but I'm wondering if there is any more natural way to do this.

```sh
for user in $(rabbitmqctl list_users --no-table-headers --quiet | awk '{print $1}'); do
    echo "$user:"
    rabbitmqctl list_user_permissions --quiet --no-table-headers $user
    echo ""
done
```

or as one line:

`for user in $(rabbitmqctl list_users --no-table-headers --quiet | awk '{print $1}'); do echo "$user:" && rabbitmqctl list_user_permissions --quiet --no-table-headers $user && echo ""; done`